# python web copy continuously throws TypeError: multiple bases have instance lay-out conflict

Tags: python, pip

I'm trying to follow the instructions for a coding lesson.

I am installing Python web copy but I continuously get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\pywebcopy\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from .configs import config, SESSION
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\pywebcopy\configs.py", line 18, in <module>
    from .exceptions import AccessError
  File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\pywebcopy\exceptions.py", line 46, in <module>
    class UrlTransformerNotSetup(PywebcopyError, UnboundLocalError):
TypeError: multiple bases have instance lay-out conflict
```

Things I've tried:

1. Uninstalling then reinstalling pyweb copy as well as python and pip
2. Moving around files
3. Adding pip to path.

   - D:\Python\Lib # this is the path for pip
   - D:\Python # Path for python

Comment: This looks like a bug in the library you are trying to use. Have you checked their bug tracker? Which precise version of the library, on which precise Python version?

Comment: Can you also link to the instructions you are trying to follow?